# How to use ENTITY to split up server.xml for Tomcat on z/OS?

Tags: xml, tomcat, entity, zos, server.xml

I am trying to split Tomcat's server.xml into multiple files.  Using ENTITY appears to be what I'm looking for, but I run into a problem where it is not looking in the right location for the file specified.

I have also tried using a system property to define the path for the ENTITY, but that appears to not be allowed.

Hard coding the absolute path works here, but this is not an option as several different tomcat instances will be using this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE server-xml [
    <!ENTITY connector-secure SYSTEM "connector_secure.xml">
]>

...

    <Service name="Catalina">
        &connector-secure;

        ...

    </Service>
```

I expect this to find the connector_secure.xml file in the `"${catalina.base}"/conf` directory (`/a/scajo/deploy/productx/tomcat/conf`) along with the server.xml file.

Instead, I receive a `FileNotFoundException` which displays the incorrect path where it is actually looking for it:

> WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /a/scajo/connector_unsecure.xml (EDC5129I No such file or directory.)

Comment: Is this on a mainframe? You tagged it 'zos' so I assume it is even though you did not tag it 'mainframe'. File not found can be caused by insufficient access authority. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

Your config-root-path seems to point at "/a/scajo/". So you can try the relative path from this root: "productx/tomcat/conf/connector_secure.xml".

As XML:

```
<!DOCTYPE server-xml [
    <!ENTITY connector-secure SYSTEM "productx/tomcat/conf/connector_secure.xml">
]>
```

(Don't know if this meets you requirements with different tomcat instances...)